# Nodejs Inserting multiple rows into postgres errors on data

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a script reads data from a json file and inserts them into postgres.  Well, that's what it's supposed to do.

The json is read properly and I can see the data as an array in the variables.  The connection is made to postgres successfully.

Then I get this error:

syntax error at or near "'{"Archived":"false","ClientEmail":"imaclientcompany@gmail.com","ClientId":52,"ClientName":"Ima Client","DateCreated":1637074825658,"DateSubmitted":1637076927912,"ExternalClientId":"null","Id":"8b9391c0-00af-4710-9481-e0e33ddea546","Practitioner":"bob@jonesperformancecenter.com","PractitionerId":"57b49e3d12cd2f144cebb405","PractitionerName":"Bob Jones","QuestionnaireId":"612524e13ccc040f58dd134e","QuestionnaireName":"PTS Pre Session Form","Status":"Completed"}'" at character 224.

The details of the error:
length: 566,
severity: 'ERROR',
code: '42601',
detail: undefined,
hint: undefined,
position: '224',
internalPosition: undefined,
internalQuery: undefined,
where: undefined,
schema: undefined,
table: undefined,
column: undefined,
dataType: undefined,
constraint: undefined,
file: 'scan.l',
line: '1145',
routine: 'scanner_yyerror'

Character 224 is in the middle of the Id field.

The 42601 error is a syntax with no hint or detail.  When I google 'scanner_yyerror' all the hits refer to unescaped single quotes.  There are no single quotes in the data.

Here is the script:

```
const pg = require('pg');
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const format = require('pg-format');
const fs = require('fs');

let rawintakes = fs.readFileSync('./data/intakes.json', 'utf8');
let intakes = JSON.parse(rawintakes);

let query1 = format('INSERT INTO intake_summary (Archived, ClientEmail, ClientId, ClientName, DateCreated, DateSubmitted, ExternalClientId, Id, Practitioner, PractitionerId, PractitionerName, QuestionnaireId, QuestionnaireName, Status) VALUES  %L returning id', intakes);

async function run() {
  let client;
  try {
    client = new pg.Pool({
      connectionString: 'postgres://postres:reallystrongpassword@localhost:5432/cldba01'
    });
    await client.connect();
    let {rows} = await client.query(query1, intakes);
    console.log(rows);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    client.end();
  }
}

run();
```

I can input the same data using SQL without a problem.  I have deleted the first record and the same problem occurs on the second one at the same position 224.

I've looked at the query and I don't see a syntax error there either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to use [SEQUELIZE](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html) instead of SQL , it is far easier and more clear.

Comment: Thanks.  I was using that but had some different issues.  I may switch back.

Comment: Sequelize did give me a lot more control over the insert and it worked.  Thanks